# SQLALCHEMY: Perform bulk SELECT statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I was trying to send a bunch of select statements to a single database using sqlalchemy unfortunately, my approach did not succeed. All my queries are also conditioned to look into indexed columns. I filter on a list of different combinations for the conditions.  Here is my current approach

```
condition1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
condition2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

queries_collection = []

for condition_value1 in condition1:

    for condition_value2  in condition2:

        condition = and_(
                        DataModel.column1 == int(condition_value1),
                        DataModel.column2 ==  int(condition_value2))

        queries_collection.append(

           self.db.session.query(DataModel).filter(condition)

        )


self.db.session.add_all(queries_collection)
result = self.db.session.execute()
```

Following an example of how to use add_all() found here https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/FilteredQuery

Generally, can I first create all queries and then execute them in bulk?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

```
result = self.db.session.query(DataModel).\
    filter(DataModel.column1.in_(condition1),
           DataModel.column2.in_(condition2)).\
    all()
```

if you're looking for combinations (product) of conditions 1 & 2.

[`Session.add_all()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all) is for adding a list of ([transient](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html)) model objects to the session.

Comment: I am looking not for any combination, but every combination from the values in condition1 & condition2.

Comment: The query will yield every combination you have stored. The word "any" meant that a single row having any combination matches the predicate.

Comment: In other words it answers "(I want to) find values in the database for all possible combinations of condition1 and condition2."

Comment: great, thanks! that did indeed solve my problem! and just a single line of code if you want!

Answer (score 1):

Make one query rather than a list of queries

```
query = db.session.query(DataModel)

for condition_value1 in condition1:

    for condition_value2  in condition2:

        condition = and_(
                    DataModel.column1 == int(condition_value1[0]),
                    DataModel.column2 ==  int(condition_value2[0])

        )

    query = query.filter(condition)

result = query.all()
```

Comment: thanks, tobey. the reason why I use lists is that I want to find values in the database for all possible combinations of condition1 and condition2. Thus, I will need to execute different queries, right? Just don't want to execute the queries already in the loop. I updated my question accordingly.